# C# label size wrong when just added to container

Tags: c#, controls, flowlayoutpanel

I have already found a workaround for this problem by using `TextTenderer.MeasureText`, but non-the-less i am very confused as to why this happens. I have here a piece of code:

```
var label = new Label() { Name = col.ColumnName, Text = col.ColumnText + ":", AutoSize = true, Margin = new Padding(1, 1, 1, 0), Font = label8.Font };
label.MaximumSize = new Size(148, 0);

Control input = null;
// Do stuff to input but not label

flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label);
flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(input);
flowLayoutPanel2.Height += label.Height + input.Height + 5;
```

Before the label is added to the flowLayoutPanel, the preferred height and width of the label is respectively 16 and 78 (which is fine), but after adding the label the actual height and width is now 176 and 16. I don't really understand where the height of 176 comes from, but it is the same number (176) every time. The height should be 16 but width apparently takes on that value

Of all 5 labels and 5 other controls added to the panel, only the second label added, which is the third control in total, experiences this. After adding the label and the program reaches the shown piece of code once again, the size of the label is suddenly correct.

If anyone can tell me what is happening, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: The code is fine, the problem must come from other parts of your code.

Comment: No other parts have any effects on the label and it is only the second label that experiences this. This is run in a foreach loop and does the same each time. I can't figure out what other parts that should be.

Comment: The code you show doesn't reproduce the issue here. Of course you don't show the loop or a hint of the data.

Comment: I guess it's just my computer then? Showing all of the loop would only be adding noise, since it is quite big. You'd need the whole code to understand it and it is not THAT pressing. I was simply wondering what it could be :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because when a Label has its parent changed, it will resize itself when AutoSize is set to true (taken from [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,fd0a0d114f49bf7a,references)) :

```
protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnParentChanged(e);
    if (SelfSizing) {
        // VSWhidbey 368232: in the case of SelfSizing
        // we dont know what size to be until we're parented
        AdjustSize();
    }
    Animate();
}
```

Same thing happend in the Visual Studio Designer if you place a Label inside a FlowLayoutPanel, then you will see its size will automatically be updated.